# Techniques For Identifying Classes And Their Responsibilites

Tags: oop, architecture, software-design

I am looking for ways (techniques) that can help me to identify classes (and probably their responsibilities) in a software system (project). I know there are many software design books but am looking specifically for how to know that this should be a class in a system and these are its responsibilities.

I want to improve my skills in how to come up with a list of classes for software projects.
Are there techniques that will help me to know the list of classes after reading the specification and requirements documents?

Please am not looking for design pattern books. I am rather looking for the techniques i can employ to come up with classes for software projects.

I welcome all your contributions, books suggestions, pointers to articles, tutorials etc.

I have googled but couldn't find any meaningful thing.

Thanks for helping.

**Addition::**

Another area that is also important is how to determine the collaboration between classes. How to determine which class needs the other.

Comment: You have to start by praying that they have a proper naming convention, and the programmers found the perfect name for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there techniques that will help me to know the list of classes **after reading the specification and requirements documents**?

No. That's terribly naive.

Every software solution is a mix of classes that have 2 purposes: meet the "problem domain" requirements and meet the "derived" requirements. Derived requirements, loosely speaking, are a result of all the technical things you gotta do like save to a database.  That these two have to meet/interact is a big reason why we have design patterns.

The trick (aka technique) for you is to focus on your business requirements and sculpt classes that express those requirements as properties and methods. Stay away from computer stuff. If you're required to "save the person data", fine. But don't go off worrying about *how* you'll do that. Design to express your "business model" in business terms and concepts.

A good place to start is as @FridayChlis says, nouns == classes, action verbs == methods. And I'd add that adjectives (often) == properties.

Refine your design by designing scenarios of how those classes interact, to wit: "a `Person` goes to the `Bank` and `Withdraws` `Money`". In this way you see how your classes interact and you'll discover the flaws and shortcomings in your design and in the requirements. Repeat the process as often as necessary until you have all your business requirements covered.

Research [UML diagramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). This is a standardized set of diagrams for software system design (and documentation!). Warning. Don't go trying to use all, or even most of the diagrams available.

Answer (score 4):

Usually nouns transfer best into classes from requirements with verbs being methods, adjectives being annotations.

.ie The car starts its engine

Class: Car
Method: startEngine()

Comment: actually I think you mean verbs should be methods